# SolR 4.0 test with AbstractSolrTestCase

Tags: java, solr, solrj, solr4

I had a test environment for SolR 3.6 and I'm trying to migrate it to 4.0, but I'm getting the following error.

The main source code is as follows:

```
public class SolrConfigTest extends AbstractSolrTestCase {
    String container = "mycore";

    @Override
    public String getSolrHome() {
        return System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resources/";
    }

    @Override
    public String getSchemaFile() {
        return getSolrHome() + container + "/conf/schema.xml";
    }

    @Override
    public String getSolrConfigFile() {
        return getSolrHome() + container + "/conf/solrconfig.xml";
    }

    @Before
    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        CoreContainer.Initializer initializer = new CoreContainer.Initializer();
        coreContainer = initializer.initialize();
        server = new EmbeddedSolrServer(coreContainer, "mycore");
    }
}
```

The solr folder structure:

```
+solr
   +mycore
      +conf
      +data
      +lib
```

The solr.xml config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr persistent="false">
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="mycore" host="${host:}" hostPort="${jetty.port:}" hostContext="${hostContext:}" zkClientTimeout="${zkClientTimeout:15000}">
    <core name="mycore" instanceDir="mycore" />
  </cores>
</solr>
```

However, when I execute this code, I get the following error:

> ```
>  [java] 16-dic-2012 0:43:15 SolrConfig <init>
>  [java] 16-dic-2012 0:43:15 org.apache.solr.util.AbstractSolrTestCase setUp
>  [java] INFO: ####SETUP_START <unknown>
>  [java] 16-dic-2012 0:43:15 org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader <init>
>  [java] INFO: new SolrResourceLoader for directory: '/home/user/workspace/tech/SolrTest/resources//collection1/'
>  [java] 16-dic-2012 0:43:16 org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig initLibs
>  [java] INFO: Adding specified lib dirs to ClassLoader
>  [java] 16-dic-2012 0:43:16 org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig <init>
>  [java] INFO: Using Lucene MatchVersion: LUCENE_40
>  [java] 16-dic-2012 0:43:16 org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig <init>
>  [java] INFO: Loaded SolrConfig: /home/user/workspace/tech/SolrTest/resources/mycore/conf/solrconfig.xml
>  [java] 16-dic-2012 0:43:16 org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema readSchema
>  [java] INFO: Reading Solr Schema
>  [java] 16-dic-2012 0:43:16 org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema readSchema
>  [java] INFO: Schema name=mycore
>  [java] 16-dic-2012 0:43:17 org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema readSchema
>  [java] INFO: unique key field: ID
>  [java] java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'stopwords.txt' in classpath or
> ```
>
> '/home/user/workspace/tech/SolrTest/resources//collection1/conf/', cwd=/home/user/workspace/tech/SolrTest
>        [java]   at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.(IndexSchema.java:116)

It seems like SolR can't find solr.xml (but does find solrconfig.xml) and that's why tries to access to collection1 (I've read that, if solr doesn't locate solr.xml, sets the core to collection1), but getSolrHome() is pointing to the folder where solr.xml is stored.

What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

You probably specified the wrong solr home.

Try below,

```
    @Override
    public String getSolrHome() {
        return System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resources/solr";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the errors appears to be that the file `stopwords.txt` is missing from the `conf` folder for Solr. Can you confirm that a stopwords.txt file exists in the directory `/home/user/workspace/tech/SolrTest/resources/mycore/conf/`

This error is being reported because an analyzer/filter for a fieldType in your schema file is referencing the stopwords.txt file.

Comment: Yes, it exists at that directory. However, you can see that Solr is looking for such file at /home/user/workspace/tech/SolrTest/resources/collection1/conf. I've read that on test mode, the core is hardcoded to collection1. Is that right?

Comment: Sorry, I have not ever used test mode, so I do not know if the core is hardcoded to collection1 in that case.